# Strict or Transitional?

Tags: html

Why should I use a "Strict" doctype vs "Transitional"?  It seems like "Strict" is like it says, more strict.  I seem to have a hard time getting things to work (css) properly vs using transitional.

Comment: Are you talking about HTML 4.01, XHTML 1 or HTML in general?
HTML5 has only one doctype and it's basically transitional.

Comment: That should be "... and it's basically strict".

Comment: HTML 4.01 and XHTML 1 are supposed to be the same structure expressed in different languages (SGML and XML respectively), so it doesn't make a difference. Other versions of (X)HTML don't have Strict/Transitional lines, so the question can't be discussing them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Transitional is, essentially, "Strict + things that should almost never be used".

So use Strict until you find yourself needing something that Transitional adds, and then think very hard about if you really need to use that element or attribute.

There should be no differences in the ways that browsers treat CSS when you switch between those Doctypes, unless you use the short form of the HTML 4.01 Transitional Doctype (i.e. without the URI) or are using HTML 4.0 (don't, it has no benefits over 4.01 at all).