# why we use Strict doctype

Tags: html, doctype

I was reading about doctypes and I read about Strict and Transitional doctypes. There are some differences between them: like strict doctype does not support tags like font etc but, Transitional does. Now I am confused as to why we use the strict doctype if transitional supports all tags. Then why do we need to use Strict doctype? Is there any reason for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strict or Transitional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3513042/strict-or-transitional)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as browser behavior (and search engines etc.) goes, there is no difference between Transitional and Strict doctype, as long as you use the versions specified in the HTML 4.01 specification. They both trigger “standards mode”, to the extent a browser has one.

So the difference matters only in validation (and as documentation to people reading the markup). Markup validators play by doctypes, so when using a Strict doctype, they well flag as errors any constructs that are not allowed in the Strict version.

Comment: That's not correct. 4.01 Transitional triggers `limited-quirks` mode.

Comment: As for what triggers which mode, there's [a nice overview on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types). The [differences](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko%27s_%22Almost_Standards%22_Mode) between standards and almost-standards (== limited-quirks) modes are very subtle though. In most cases you won't even realize them.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Nevertheless, questions like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10988798/mysterious-bottom-padding-in-css are an almost weekly occurrence on SO, which often come when a web author tries to switch from HTML 4.01 Transitional or XHTML 1.0 Transitional to HTML5.

Comment: @Pumbaa80 - Incidentally, the Wikipedia article is rather misleading. It limits the difference to images inside table cells. Although that's the most common case, it's a fair bit wider than that. I believe that it's more like all replaced inline elements in line-boxes.

Answer (score 4):

If you start a new project, just go with html5, it only has one DOCTYPE:

`<!DOCTYPE html>`

Back to your original question, Here's a good article:

http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup

> A Transitional DOCTYPE may be used when you have a lot of legacy markup that cannot easily be converted to comply with a Strict DOCTYPE. But Strict is what you should be aiming for. It encourages, and in some cases enforces, the separation of structure and presentation, moving the presentational aspects from markup to CSS.

Answer (score 1):

> Using a Strict DTD, either HTML 4.01 Strict or XHTML 1.0 Strict, is
>   far more important for the quality of the future web than whether or
>   not there is an X in front of the name. The Strict DTD promotes a
>   separation of structure and presentation, which makes a site so much
>   easier to maintain.

Read [**this**](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup) and [**this**](http://24ways.org/2005/transitional-vs-strict-markup).